# Right multiplication by matrix with orthonogonal columns and its affect on the smallest singular values

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd

Following up on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3343697/how-will-the-singular-values-change-after-multiplying-a-rectangular-orthogonal-m?rq=1) question: Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ be a matrix such that $m \ll n$ and let $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$   with $r<m$ such that $Q^TQ = I$.

By Courant–Fischer Max-Min theorem, we have that the spectrum of $Q^T A^T A Q $ is contained in that of $A^T A$.

However, the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/592621/ernie060) to the linked question states that for all $i=1,\dots,r$ we have that $\sigma_{\min} (A) \leq  \sigma_i (AQ) \leq \sigma_{\max}(A)$, and I guess that this answer takes into account the broadest definition of singular values, in which $\sigma_{\min}(A) = 0 $, and in this case, the lower bound on the smallest **non zero** singular value of $AQ$ is trivial (0).

When considering only non zero singular values, then the claim that $\sigma_{\min} (A) \leq  \sigma_i (AQ)$ does not hold anymore. For example, consider

$$A = \left[ \begin{matrix}
-2 & 1 &  3 &  4 \\
 -4 & 3 & 2 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 3& -4 \\
\end{matrix}\right] \text{ and } 
Q = \left[ \begin{matrix}
1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\
1/\sqrt{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 1/\sqrt{2} \\
0 & 1/\sqrt{2}
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
then the singular values of $A$ are : $\sigma_1 (A) = 6.82, ~\sigma_2 (A) =  5.92,~ \sigma_3 (A) =  2.74 $, and for $AQ$ we have $\sigma_1 (AQ) = 5.34, ~\sigma_2 (AQ) =  1.98$.

When only non zero singular values are considered, we have that $\sigma_{\min} (AQ) = \sigma_2 (AQ) =  1.98 < \sigma_{\min}(A) = \sigma_3 (A) = 2.74$.

Is there a way to bound the smallest non-zero singular value of $AQ$ from below?

Comment: @Ernie060 as  the one who answered the original question - do you have any ideas?

Comment: I think the result works for $m\ge n$

Comment: @Exodd sure, there is a nice explanation for this case in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481734/the-smallest-non-zero-singular-value-of-ab

This answer also rules out the existence of a non trivial lower bound when $m \ll n$ and general matrices $A$ and $B$. But here $Q$ is not a general matrix, it has orthogonal columns. And I'm trying to figure out if there's something we can say

Comment: if $m<n/2$ you can easily find $Q$ such that $AQ=0$: just take the columns of $Q$ in the orthogonal space of the rows of $A$